# What is meant By 'WARN o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder - Empty encoded password in spring security?'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am implementing spring security in existing web app, when im trying to login I'm getting response as bad credentials(Even when the credentials are right) when i tried looking in logs i got something as

> WARN  o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder - Empty encoded password

Is this a reason for bad credentials?

Here is my code

```
  @PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(accountDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
    }
}


 @Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: I think the message is clear. There is no encoded Password: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means what it says, literally. In case of similar doubts, please take a look into a source code.

Below code comes from `package org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt;`

```
public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
    if (encodedPassword == null || encodedPassword.length() == 0) {
        logger.warn("Empty encoded password");
        return false;
    }
    if (!BCRYPT_PATTERN.matcher(encodedPassword).matches()) {
        logger.warn("Encoded password does not look like BCrypt");
        return false;
    }
    return BCrypt.checkpw(rawPassword.toString(), encodedPassword);
}
```

As you can see:

> encodedPassword == null || encodedPassword.length() == 0

hence your warning.